# Array SQLITE: how to color rows?

Tags: php, arrays, colors

Problem:
My HTML table from SQLITE database does notlook good on the top right side.
[image: two colors]

In the right row ("Count") the different numbers should have different colors.

23 and 17 are different numbers but have the same color, because both are odd. They should have different colours.
Same problem is on numbers 9 and 7.

PHP Code is here:

```
    <?php
    $result = $db->query("SELECT http_host, request_uri,COUNT(request_uri) as 
    'sum' FROM $tablename1[$sid] GROUP BY http_host,request_uri ORDER BY sum 
    DESC");
    $i=0;
    $countt=0;
    $iminus=0;
    $total=0;
    $bright = "style= 'background-color: #cecece;'";//test other color
    $dark = "style= 'background-color: #779BAB;'";//test other color
    foreach($result as $row)
        {
        $i++;
        if ($i == $n_vis){break;}
        $timestamp = $row[timestamp];
        $atime = intval(substr($timestamp,8,2));
        $xtime = substr($timestamp,0,9);
        $http_host = $row[http_host];
        $http_host = htmlentities($http_host,ENT_QUOTES);
        $request_uri = $row[request_uri];
        $request_uri = htmlentities($request_uri,ENT_QUOTES);
        $sum = $row[sum];
        $total=$total+$sum;
        $count[$i]=$sum;
        $stile[$i]=$stile;
        //Change background////////////////////////////////////////
        if ((((intval($sum))%2)==0)) {$stile="style= 'background-color: 
        #cecece;'";}
        if ((((intval($sum))%2)>0)) {$stile="style= 'background-color: #779BAB;'";}
        echo "<tr $stile><td align='right'>$i</td>";
        echo "<td>$http_host$request_uri</td><td align='right'>$sum</td></tr>";
        }
    ?>
```

I tried to solve the problem by adding this PHP code:

```
    reset($result);
    while($row = $result->fetchArray()){
        $sum = $row[sum];
        $count[$i]=$sum;
        $stile[$i]=$stile;
        if(($count[$i] > $count[$i-1])==("" OR 0 OR -1))
            {$stile=$dark;}
        if(($count[$i] > $count[$i-1]) && ($stile[$i-1]==$dark))
            {$stile=$bright;}
        if(($count[$i] > $count[$i-1]) && ($stile[$i-1]==$bright))
            {$stile=$dark;}
        if(($count[$i] == $count[$i-1]) && ($stile[$i-1]==$dark))
            {$stile=$dark;}
        if(($count[$i] == $count[$i-1]) && ($stile[$i-1]==$bright))
            {$stile=$bright;}
        echo "<tr $stile><td align='right'>$i</td>";
        echo "<td>$http_host$request_uri</td><td    align='right'>$sum</td></tr>";
        }
    echo "</table></center>";
```

But this additional code does not change anything.

So I did this temporary solution:

```
    <?php
    $result = $db->query("SELECT http_host, request_uri, COUNT(request_uri) as 'sum' FROM $tablename1[$sid] GROUP BY http_host,request_uri ORDER BY sum DESC");
    $i=0;
    foreach($result as $row){
        $i++;
        if ($i == $n_vis){break;}
        $timestamp = $row[timestamp];
        $atime = intval(substr($timestamp,8,2));
        $xtime = substr($timestamp,0,9);
        $http_host = $row[http_host];
        $http_host = htmlentities($http_host,ENT_QUOTES);
        $request_uri = $row[request_uri];
        $request_uri = htmlentities($request_uri,ENT_QUOTES);
        $sum = $row[sum];
        $total=$total+$sum;
        //Change background////////////////////////////////////////
        if (((((intval($sum))%2)==0))){$stile="style= 'background-color: #cecece;'";}
        if (((((intval($sum))%2)==0)) && (((intval($sum))%3)==0)){$stile="style= 'background-color: #add8e6;'";}
        if (((((intval($sum))%2)>0))){$stile="style= 'background-color: #779BAB;'";}
        if (((((intval($sum))%3)==0))  && (((intval($sum))%2)<>0)) {$stile="style= 'background-color: #779BAB'";}
        if (((((intval($sum))%3)>0))  && (((intval($sum))%2)<>0)) {$stile="style= 'background-color: #8fbc8f;'";}
        if (((((intval($sum))%4)==1))  && (((intval($sum))%2)<>0)) {$stile="style= 'background-color: #f0e68c;'";}
        if ($sum==1){$stile="style= 'background-color: #779BAB;'";} //Change background
        echo "<tr $stile><td align='right'>$i</td>";
        echo "<td>$http_host$request_uri</td><td align='right'>$sum</td></tr>";
        }
    echo "<tr><td align='right'>.</td>";
    echo "<td>total</td><td align='right'>$total</td></tr>";
    echo "</table></center>";
    ?>
```

It looks correct but it looks too much colorful, see here:
[image: multi colors]

If possible, I want display it only with two colors.

Is there a PHP solution?
Thx in advance for your hints.

Comment: This is HTML/CSS, not server side. Edit the tags.

Comment: Well, the obvious solution is to iterate over the table content and not down a flag which you toggle each time that count value changes between rows. You can then derive a css class from that flag. Which you can use to assign a background color by means of css.

Comment: For information: the table shown is a table of a counter. The table changes / increases every day.